# Replace values below value with same value until new unique value appears R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the columns `name`, `date` and `value` .

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Apple",NULL,NULL,"Banana",NULL,NULL),
                    date = c("01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012",
                             "01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012"),
                    value = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

```
#the df

      name      date          value
1      Apple    01.01.2010      1
2      NULL     01.01.2011      2
3      NULL     01.01.2012      3
4      Banana   01.01.2010      1
5      NULL     01.01.2011      2
6      NULL     01.01.2012      3
```

somehow I cant get to the desired output below...

I tried

```
  
df_new <- df%>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(name)
```

But it doesnt work

I wish to get a `df` like this. My `df` is however a lot longer than this example.

```
#the df

      name      date          value
1      Apple    01.01.2010      1
2      Apple    01.01.2011      2
3      Apple    01.01.2012      3
4      Banana   01.01.2010      1
5      Banana   01.01.2011      2
6      Banana   01.01.2012      3
```

Comment: Please check the `df` shared. There are no `NULL` values in it.

Answer (score 2):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    mutate(name = replace(name, name == "NULL", NA)) %>%
    fill(name)
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Apple","NULL","NULL","Banana","NULL","NULL"),
                 date = c("01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012",
                          "01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012"),
                 value = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"NULL"` as character value, you may change them to `NA` before using `fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(name = na_if(name, 'NULL')) %>%
  fill(name)

#    name       date value
#1  Apple 01.01.2010     1
#2  Apple 01.01.2011     2
#3  Apple 01.01.2012     3
#4 Banana 01.01.2010     1
#5 Banana 01.01.2011     2
#6 Banana 01.01.2012     3
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Apple","NULL","NULL","Banana","NULL","NULL"),
                 date = c("01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012",
                          "01.01.2010","01.01.2011","01.01.2012"),
                 value = c(1,2,3,1,2,3))
```